# java - ensuring that method will be called at the end of child class construction

Tags: java, methods, transparent, invocation

I've got abstract class :

```
public abstract class MyComposite extends Composite {

     protected abstract void initHandlers();
}
```

And a buch of classes which extends it. How to ensure that method initHandlers() is going to be called at the end of child classes construction? Example child class:

```
public CollWidget extends MyComposite {
    public CollWidget() {
        /** Some stuff thats need to be done in this particular case */
        initHandlers(); // This method should be invoked transparently
    }

    @Override
    public void initHandlers() {
        /** Handlers initialisation, using some components initialized in constructor */
    }
}
```

Comment: No way to make it happen automatically.

Comment: No way. See if you can avoid this by going back to the design, and if you really can't, clearly document this behaviour and let users fail miserably if they don't read the documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it automatically, since the parent constructor is always called before the child one (explicitely or implicitely).

One <strike>solution</strike> workaround could be:

```
public abstract class MyComposite {

    public MyComposite() {
        construct();
        initHandlers();
    }

    protected abstract void construct();

    protected abstract void initHandlers();

}

public class CollWidget extends MyComposite {

    @Override
    protected void construct() {
        // called firstly
    }

    @Override
    public void initHandlers() {
        // called secondly
    }

}
```

Comment: Construct() method is quite good around, but in presenter which contains those widgets i have to call this method explicity, while constructor is called by default. I need to inform binder that's im constructing object on my own as well, without default constructor usage. Therefore instead one extra line for each widget i've got few of them :)

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak Well, the parent nullary constructor is also called by default implicitely, so you won't need to add any extra line other than `new CollWidget()`. See http://ideone.com/KxkPeA.